# Ruby - Adding more than one includes on an if statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement, include

I have the following code which works fine

```
if user_input.include? "s"
    user_input.gsub!(/s/ "th")
else
    print "Nothing to change"
end
```

But when I want to add another `include` like so it does not recognize the `elsif` How do I add these includes together?

```
if user_input.include? "s"
    user_input.gsub!(/s/ "th")
elsif user_input.include? "cee"
    user_input.gsub!(/cee/ "th")
else
    print "Nothing to change"
end
```

Comment: could you add an example input/output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of flow of execution of if else statement.
If condition in 'if' matches it will not execute 'elseif' block..

```
if user_input.include?('s') or user_input.include?('cee')
  user_input.gsub!(/s/,"th").gsub!(/cee/,"th")
else
  print "Nothing to change"
end
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `gsub!` returns `nil` if nothing changed, your can write your example just like this:

```
unless user_input.gsub!(/s|cee/ "th")
  print "Nothing to change"
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code show the error :

```
SyntaxError: unexpected ')', expecting keyword_end
```

You forget the commas in gsub

```
if user_input.include? "s"
    user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
elsif user_input.include? "cee"
    user_input.gsub!(/cee/, "th")
else
    print "Nothing to change"
end
```

Edit : 
If you want to make both replacement, you need to change to :

```
old_value = user_input
if user_input.include? "s"
    user_input.gsub!(/s/, "th")
end
if user_input.include? "cee"
    user_input.gsub!(/cee/, "th")
end

if user_input == old8value   
    print "Nothing to change"
end
```

Comment: Thanks that sorted out the errors but it is still disregarding the include of "s" it only replaces "cee"

Comment: You want to do both replacement ? You can't like this. Else means "in the other case". If the first statement is done, the others are not.

Comment: Thanks that make sense that it would require two separate if statements for each query.

Answer (score 1):

Once the first `if` is matched, the rest are skipped.

For your particular use case, I would suggest that you use a single `gsub` like so:

```
regexp = /s|cee/

if string.match(regexp)
  string.gsub!(regexp, "th")
else
  "Nothing to gsub!"
end
```